# Node JS - Supertest - Getting ECONNRESET when sending response

Tags: node.js, supertest

We wanted to test our node server with supertest but we faced the present problem.

To synthetize the problem, the following code :

```
var express = require("express");
var request = require("supertest")

var app = express();

app.post('/test_multipart', function(req, res, next){
    res.status(200).send("ok")  
})

var supertest = request(app);

function test(){
    supertest
        .post('/test_multipart')
        .field("pseudo", "test")
        .attach('pdf_file', 'test.pdf')
        .end(function(err, res){
            console.log(err)
            console.log(res)
        })
}
test();
```

provokes the following console log :

```
{ 
    [Error: read ECONNRESET]
    code: 'ECONNRESET',
    errno: 'ECONNRESET',
    syscall: 'read',
    response: undefined 
}
undefined
```

So, this means that res becomes undefined between the moment we sent it and the moment supertest is receptioning it. This is probably due to the fact we send a response before all the request has been read. But we precisely want to send response before the end of the request. We couldn't determine if this is a supertest bug or an expected behaviour and if so, how to manage it...
Maybe, someone knows ?

Comment: did you forget to add body-parser? try removing the `.attach('pdf_file', 'test.pdf’)` line

Comment: Thanks for your comment and sorry for the late answer. The body-parser middleware consumes all the request before transmitting it, that's why we don't use it. And, indeed, if I remove the  `.attach`, the operation works. But, doing that, it is not possible to test the send of a file.

Comment: I think you'll need a middleware to handle file uploads. something like [multer](https://github.com/expressjs/multer). if it works, try taking a look at its source code and figure out what you need to do.

Comment: To be more precise, we use a formidable parser ([link](https://github.com/felixge/node-formidable)), but what we do is, when transfert data has incorrect format, to let the request go its way and to send a response to the client. The above code is only a synthesis of the problem. The above express app works well when making a server, but doesn't work when testing by supertest.

Comment: @Personne I am also experiencing the exact same problem. Mine was failing on `.expect()` until i messed with the supertest source. It was returning undefined for the response under the hood. When I ignored that, I got your error.

Comment: @Personne, did you ever find a solution or work around this this? I'm running into the same thing trying to test my `busboy` based multipart middleware.